# Where is the template "sitename/index.php/api/login" in EE2?

Tags: php, codeigniter, expressionengine

How do I find the template file: `sitename/index.php/api/login` in EE2 (expressionengine)? I did not create a template group called api so where did this `sitename/index.php/api/login` come from and where is it?

Comment: when i looked it i found that it it comes from Open API extension but when i tried this add-on on local server i didn't get API METHOD called "login" so how can i add login API METHOD in this add-on ?